# Is it possible to transition placeholder text from beginning to end?

Tags: css, placeholder

I would like to transition a single line of dynamic placeholder text from beginning to end within a text input of known width (which hides overflow)

Now I know that for a regular container div I can make use of transforms to transition the correct length...

so for a container of length 100px I could transition to the end of the text with: `transform: translateX(calc(100px - 100%)`

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: 4s scrollText forwards;
}

@keyframes scrollText {
  to {
      transform: translateX(calc(100px - 100%));
  }
}
```

```html
<div><span>some really really really long text here</span></div>
```

I was wondering if I could achieve the above effect with placeholder text using the [placeholder pseudo element](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#placeholder-pseudo).

So I tried the following:

```css
input {
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: red;
  animation: 4s scrollText;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

@keyframes scrollText {
  from {
      transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
      transform: translateX(calc(100px - 100%));
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="some really really really long text here">
```

... but the above snippet doesn't work because of a limitation of the properties available on the placeholder pseudo element

> All properties that apply to the [::first-line pseudo-element](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#selectordef-first-line) also
>   apply to the ::placeholder pseudo-element.

Unfortunately, `transform`<sup>1</sup> doesn't appear in [that list](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#first-line-styling).

So I was wondering if there is another way of achieving this - possibly with other properties which **are** supported by the placeholder pseudo element.

---

1. Strangely enough, the `transform` property did seem to (sort of) work on Chrome when used without the calc function and the animation.

```css
input {
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: red;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="some really really really long text here">
```

Comment: A placeholder of such length that it would need “scrolling” is a UX fail to begin with IMHO …

Comment: @04FS I agree, but I would still like to know if it's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate this using an extra wrapper without really using a placeholder on the input element:

```css
input {
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align:top;
  background:transparent; /* a transparent background to show the pseudo element */
}


.input {
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.input:before {
  content:attr(placeholder);
  position:absolute;
  left:5px;
  top:5px;
  white-space:nowrap; /* no line break */
  color: red;
  pointer-events:none; /* avoid any interaction */
  animation: 4s scrollText forwards;
  z-index:-1;
}

@keyframes scrollText {
  to {
      transform: translateX(calc(100px - 100%));
  }
}

/* hide the before on focus */
.input:focus-within:before{
   visibility:hidden;
}

/* add background to hide the before when there is text and no focus*/
input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="input" placeholder="some really really really long text here">
<input type="text" placeholder=" "> <!-- needs an empty placeholder for :placeholder-shown -->
</div>
```

Comment: ok, thanks, I was hoping there would be a way to do this without a wrapper element... but I guess not.

Comment: @Danield yes I don't think so, but since the transform worked for the placeholder you can probably consider JS to animate it by increasing the transform