# How make bounce effect for input placeholder?

Tags: html, css

How make bounce effect for input placeholder? I need in bounceIn effect for my input placeholder. How animate this placeholder it? Now my animation not works.

```css
@keyframes bounceIn {
  from,
  20%,
  40%,
  60%,
  80%,
  to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
    transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
    transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.97, 0.97, 0.97);
    transform: scale3d(0.97, 0.97, 0.97);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}

.search {
  padding: 10px;
}

.search:focus::placeholder {
 animation: bounceIn 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<input class="search" type="text" name="Search" value="" placeholder="Search...">
```

Comment: you cannot apply animation to placeholder, here is related question to get a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55901797/8620333

Comment: It works perfectly - you can add some JS to make it only fire on focus if you like.

Comment: Hi Julupo - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below my answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer. (You won't get any points for doing so, but that will close out the question.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the `::placeholder` from:

```
.search:focus::placeholder {
    animation: bounceIn 2s infinite;
}
```

Also, you might find it best to not infinitely repeat the animation.

```css
@keyframes bounceIn {
  from,
  20%,
  40%,
  60%,
  80%,
  to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
    transform: scale3d(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
    transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.97, 0.97, 0.97);
    transform: scale3d(0.97, 0.97, 0.97);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}

.search {
  padding: 10px;
}

.search:focus {
 animation: bounceIn 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<h3>Click in input field to trigger animation</h3>
<input class="search" type="text" name="Search" value="" placeholder="Search...">
```