# How can I set a transition delay on the text-align property?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to change the text align property when my input field is hovered. I understand that you cant transition it, buts that okay, thats not what I am trying to do. What I am trying to do is I want the property to only change after the width transition is finished. I tried setting a transition delay, but this did NOT work unfortunatly. How can I achieve my desired effect then?

```css
div {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: skyblue;
  position: relative;
}
input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: right;
  width: 10rem;
  transition: width 300ms, text-align 0s 300ms;
}
input:hover {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  transition: width 300ms;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="search">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901797/is-it-possible-to-transition-placeholder-text-from-beginning-to-end

Comment: a property that cannot have transition means cannot have transition delay as well

Answer (score -1):

You need to use keyframes here.
here is a simple implementation.

```css
div {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: skyblue;
  position: relative;
}
input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: right;
}
input:hover {

  //modified to use keyframes
    animation: all 2s;
   -webkit-animation: all 2s; 
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes all {
    0%   {width: 10rem;}
    50%  {width: 100%;}
    100% {width: 100%;text-align: left;} //after the width the placeholder text will be aligned left.
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="search">
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice, however, this only works one way! How can I reverse this so the animation applies when you lose hover / focus?